# How to limit the backward dependency between coded frames in ffmpeg/x264

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, libx264

I am currently playing with ffmpeg + libx264, but i couldn't find a way to limit the backward dependency between coded frames.

Let me explain what i mean: I want the coded frames to only contain references to at most, let's say, 5 frames in the future. As a result, no frame has to "wait" for more than 5 frames to be coded (makes sense for low latency applications).

I am aware of the `-tune zerolatency` option, but that's not what i want; I still want bidirectional prediction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to limit the number of consecutive B-frames then you can use the `--bframes <integer>` x264 option or the `-bf <integer>` FFmpeg option.

See also: [Diary Of An x264 Developer - x264: the best low-latency...](http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/249)

Comment: or possibly limit the i-frames (gop option)? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Latency

Comment: It's a very interesting articel, thanks for that =) However, it focusses on very low delay applications, which is far below what i need (and has a higher bitrate trade-off than i want). I will try the B-frames thing tomorrow (the question is whether x264 will do prediction across P-frames in the B-frames. As for limiting the gop-size: I can of course limit the backward dependency through that, but there's a huge bitrate trade-off with all the I-frames.

Comment: So far this seems to work, although it's not guaranteed in the documentation, so i'll go with this approach. Thanks for your help =)